# Using Swift's Repeat collection

Tags: swift2

In pre-Swift 2.0 sample code, I've come across something like:

```
var val = "hello" + Repeat(count: paddingAmount, repeatedValue: "-") + "."
```

In Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0 Playground, this produces the error:

```
note: expected an argument list of type '(String, String)'
```

How would you use the Repeat collection and get the value that's held by the collection for use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` has an initializer that will return a string of repeated characters, I would recommend using that in your case:

```
let padding = String(count: paddingAmount, repeatedValue: Character("-"))
var val = "hello" + padding + "."
```

Comment: So any idea on why the Repeat struct definition still exists in Swift 2 header files? I can't find any sample code that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

It's now `Array(count: paddingAmount, repeatedValue: "-")`.